# FLUTTER | Right Align not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Trying to right align a container with text view child, it has a row parent which is inside another column, tried number of solutions from Stack Overflow, didn't work.

**Code**

```
///Transactions Heading
        new Column(
         children: <Widget>[
            new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 10.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "Transactions",
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      color: primaryTextColor,
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      letterSpacing: 0.1,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    currentGoalTransactions.length.toString() + " items",
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        color: darkHeadingsTextColor, fontSize: 15.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
       ]);
```

**Want to align the 2 items text to the right**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etwXn.png)

Comment: Can you please share the image which shows what actually you want?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use the **`mainAxisAlignment`** property in **`Row`** widget.

```
new Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, 
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `Spacer` which will get remaining space and will divide the widget equally

```
     Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Text 1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
          Spacer(),
          Text("Text 2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
          Spacer(),
          Text("Text 3", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
        ],
      ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

You can also try `Wrap` like this:

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 50, // spacing between each of the widgets below
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("One"),
    Text("Two"),
    Text("Three"),
  ],
)
```